# seralize multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have the following value in my database:

```
a:2:{s:4:"ques";a:2:{i:0;i:15;i:1;i:17;}s:5:"marks";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"2";}}
```

I tried to do the following to get the value into my database:

```
$question["ques"] = '15';
$question["ques"] = '17';
$question["marks"] = '1';
$question["marks"] = '1';

$questions = serialize($question);
update_post_meta($quiz_id, 'quiz_questions1', $questions);
```

This doesn't update the database correctly. The output I get using this is the following:

```
a:2:{s:4:"ques";s:2:"17";s:5:"marks";s:1:"1";}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: db normalization would make your life a whole lot easier

Comment: $question["ques"] = array('15','17');
$question["marks"] = array('2','2');

Comment: @Dagon I know but trying to modify a plugin and trying to work with the cards that I was dealt.

Comment: $question["ques"] = array(15,17);
$question["marks"] = array('2','2');    ques use integer values

Comment: U r overwrite with the last value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a serialized data structure then the simplest way to understand it is to unserialize it, and show it to yourself with a `print_r()`.

```
<?php
$s = 'a:2:{s:4:"ques";a:2:{i:0;i:15;i:1;i:17;}s:5:"marks";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"2";}}';

$array = unserialize($s);
print_r($array);
```

Which will show

```
Array
(
    [ques] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 17
        )

    [marks] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

So now you just have to duplicate that structure with your new data

```
$array = array();
$array['ques'] = array(15, 17);
$array['marks'] = array('1', '1');

// take a look to check
print_r($array);

// and if it is good. Serialize it and store it on the database
$questions = serialize($array);
update_post_meta($quiz_id, 'quiz_questions1', $questions);
```

Comment: values in "marks" are string's, check serialize.. i:0;s:1:"2";   index = 0 string = 1 value = "2"

Comment: Thanks, answer changed accordingly